# Struts2 Property Tag in Display Tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I have the following:

```
<display:table id="tbl" name="list" pagesize="3">
    <display:column title="COLUMN">
        ${tbl.date}
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

The above works but I want to replace `${tbl.date}` with Struts2 tag property to call static method.

Replacing `${tbl.date}` with `<s:property value="%{#tbl.date}"/>` didn't work. I will be using `tbl.date` as parameter in calling static method in Struts2.:

```
<s:property value="@SomeStaticClass@method(tbl.date)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<s:property value="%{@SomeStaticClass@method(#attr.tbl.date)}"/>
```

after adding `uid="tbl"` to `<display:table>`