# Use Struts2's <s:property> tag in <display:table> tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

I am trying to add a list into a table using DisplayTag.

Everything works normally when I add list property to a column in the usual manner:

```
<display:column property="status" title="Claim Status"/>
<display:column property="authNo" title="Authorization Number" href="authSlipMasterAction">
```

Now, I want to check when authNo is not blank; if it is blank, then do not provide the link, so how can I use `<s:if test=''>` and `<s:property value="">` in the `<display:table>` tag ?

I've tried to display the value using `<s:property value="authNo"/>` but no value is shown (I have to display the value because I want to check the condition)

This is my code

```
   <display:table uid="myTable" id="display-tag" name="session.claimReportList">
   <display:column title="Authorization No"> 
    <s:property value="#attr.myTable.transNo" />
</display:column>
```

I have also tried

```
      <s:property value="#session.myTable.transNo" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use DisplayTag with nested Lists and Properties in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762072/how-to-use-displaytag-with-nested-lists-and-properties-in-struts-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `#attr.` notation in your `<s:property />` or `<s:if />` when inside a DisplayTag column; you also need to [use the `uid` specified in the `<display:table>` tag after the `#attr.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954782/1654265) to access your objects.

For example:

```xml
<display:table requestURI="actionURL" uid="myTable" />

    <display:column title="authNo">    
        <s:property value="#attr.myTable.authNo" />
    </display:column>

</display:table>
```

From [OGNL Basics - Struts 2 Named Objects](http://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Struts2NamedObjects):

> `#attr['foo']` or `#attr.foo`
>
> Access to `PageContext` if available, otherwise searches
>   `request`/`session`/`application` respectively

P.S: I'd consider taking a look at some newer grid like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) or [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/), though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the UID thing. I've added it to the answer, linking my original answer written centuries ago... please try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code inside display tag.

1.) **#attr.objectName**: attribute in page, request, session, or application scope (searched in that order)
2.) **row** is the `id` you have used for `display:table`.
3.) **authNo**: Your custom propery.

```
<s:if test="%{#attr.row.authNo != null}">
    <display:column title="Status">Your custom message</display:column>
    </s:if>
```

Hope it may help you..!!

Comment: @Can you try to print using <s:property value ="%{#attr.row.authNo}  /> without s:if condition ?