# Check if list contains elements or not

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl, struts-tags

The requirement is that I need to display some check boxes on a column in a jsp page in a table if they are configured to be displayed or not.

In My action class, I have the logic that fetches the configuration values from db and stores it an array.

Now the question is:

> should I store the array in a session or something, so that I can access it inside my decorator method and returns the appropriate HTML to display the check box or not ?
>
> Or should I traverse the list on the jsp page and see if the entry (see ID in JSP) is present in the list , then display the column ?

Personally I like the second approach, but don't know how to do it.

Here is my JSP page.

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/star" prefix="star" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>

<div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer95">

    <display:table id = "displayTable"
                 name = "contentToDisplay"
                class = "scrollTable"
            decorator = "decoractorClass">

        <display:column  property = "displayTextField()" 
                         titleKey = "ID"/>
    
        <!--Only display checkbox if ID is present in some list in action class-->
        <display:column property = "displayCheckBox()"
                        sortable = "false"
                     headerClass = "sortable" />
```

Comment: Why not to use some map?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are fine.

If you go with the client side one, you can do it in several ways (with a condition in JSTL, in OGNL, etc...).

Since you are using Struts2, use OGNL, something like:

```xml
<display:column>

    <s:if test="%{myId in someList}">
        <s:checkbox ... />
    </s:if>

</display:column>
```

Note that to get the PageContext you need to use `#attr`, and after that you need to call the table instance through its `uid`, [like described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846311/1654265).

Comment: Thanks Andrea, let me try this.